# Which is the correct version of asm, spring-asm and cglib to be used in synch with JDK 1.8 and spring 3.x?

Tags: spring, java-bytecode-asm, cglib, jvm-bytecode

Project details:
X-project uses asm.asm-2.2 cglib 2.2 version
Y-project uses spring-asm 2.x and cglib 2.2.0.b2
X-project is included as dependency in Y-project
The above projects uses apache-ivy and apache ant 1.7.0
JDK 1.8

Background:-

Y project was initially compiled using JDK 1.6 and X project was initially compiled using JDK 1.5.
Now Y project needs to be compiled and run in JAVA 1.8. Y project is successfully compiled using JDK 1.8. Y project now uses X project, which is compiled in JDK 1.5.
The versions of asm and spring-asm jars are not modified

Problem statement:-
While running junit (version-3.8.1) tests of Y-project, bytecode mismtach error occurs. i.e., Expected stackmapframe at branch target 68

Cause for this (as searched in stackoverflow) is as follows:-
asm.asm jar that manipulates the stackmap frames and bytecodes of X project.

Suspect is - Y project uses spring-asm which helps in initiating the bean in it, that in-turn accesses the classes of X project. As the classes of X project already has stackmap frames defined by asm.asm 2.2 jar, bytecodes created by spring asm of Y project mismatches with those of X project

I tried the following:-
1. changing the version of asm.asm jar to 5.0.3 in X project but did not change the version of cglib used by X project
2. Did not change the version of spring-asm used by Y project
3. When compiled the X project using Java 1.8 and tried to run its Junit test classes, cglib 2.2 jar of X project threw class not found error- i.e., it was trying to find a class in asm 5.0.3 version

Please let me know which versions of jar-asm, spring-asm and cglib needs to be used in X and Y projects in the above mentioned scenario